# How to find the built-in problem matchers' definitions?

Tags: c++, gcc, ide, visual-studio-code

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks, there may be many built-in problem matchers. For instance:

```
"label": "build",
"type": "shell",
"command": "make",
"problemMatcher": [ "$gcc", "$msCompile" ],
"group": "build"
```

**My Question**

*How to find the definitions of $gcc and $msCompile?*

Comment: go to the `package.json` file of the extension that defines the problem matcher here it is `ms-vscode.cpptools-1.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Following @rioV8's comment, I searched the directories where built-in extensions are installed (`/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions` on Linux) for `package.json` files which contain an entry `problemMatchers`. These are the ones I found:

#### Extension `vscode.less`: "Less Language Basics"

- `lessc`: label "Lessc compiler"

#### Extension `vscode.typescript-language-features`: "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features"

problem matchers:

- `tsc`: label "%typescript.problemMatchers.tsc.label%" – ?
- `tsc-watch`: label "%typescript.problemMatchers.tscWatch.label%" – ?

problem patterns:

- `tsc`

#### Extension `vscode.cpp`: "C/C++ Language Basics"

problem matchers:

- `nvcc`: no label

problem patterns:

- `nvcc-location`

#### Extension `vscode.scss`: "SCSS Language Basics"

- `node-sass`: label "Node Sass Compiler"

Strangely, this list is quite different from the one under [Processing task output with problem matchers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers) in the documentation. I couldn't find most that are listed, and I found one which isn't.